# Conditional update in Elasticsearch: "Invalid op [none]"

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

Elasticsearch 2.3. I am firing this query to update every doc in an index based on a condition.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "if (ctx._source.url.endsWith('a=6')) ctx.op = 'none' else ctx._source.url = ctx._source.url + '&b=3'"
  }
}
```

As stated [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-update.html), I am using `ctx.op = 'none'` to avoid updating the docs that do not match the condition.

I am getting

> Invalid op [none]

Full error:

```
"error": {
"root_cause": [
{
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "Invalid op [none]"
}
],
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "Invalid op [none]"
},
"status": 400
```

Seems to be so simple that I am pretty lost. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct operation is `noop`, not `none`.

From [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-update-by-query.html):

> Just as in Update API you can set ctx.op = "noop" if your script decides that it doesn’t have to make any changes. That will cause _update_by_query to omit that document from its updates.

PR created: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/24613

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be working now. So the docs for 2.3 I reference above are somehow wrong, or at least ambiguous.

Comment: The documentation itself is ok, only the example is wrong (old).